# Prevent child element's event being fired on clicking parent

Tags: jquery

The markup is as below.

```
<span id="spnMenuContainer" class="Menu">
  <div id="divContainer" class="SubMenu">                            
    <div id="BtnResubmit" class="basicbutton">Resubmit</div>
  </div>
</span>
```

Ihave some jquery code in my project like this.

```
$("#spnMenuContainer").bind("click",function(e){
   /*----
   some other code here
   -----*/
   $("#divMenuContainer").find("#BtnResubmit").bind("click",function(){
      UpdateAndRefreshTable('resub');
   });
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

but I guess the `stopPropagation` method is not working. When I click the span, the `UpdateAndRefreshTable` function is being called.How to prevent this. I need the function to work only on the `divMenuContainer` click.

Comment: Do `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` and try keeping it above 2nd `bind`

Comment: why are yo binding an events inside event

Comment: No need of find() function. IDs should be unique.only #BtnResubmit will work.

Answer (score 0):

To top bubbling of event to the parent element, add a binding to child element and use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$("#BtnResubmit").on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    UpdateAndRefreshTable('resub');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually binding the event to `spnMenuContainer`, so the `stopPropagation()` event is actually stopping the event from bubbling up from `spnMenuContainer`, not from `divMenuContainer`.

Try binding to `divMenuContainer` and using `stopPropagation()` instead:

```
$('#BtnResubmit').on('click', function(e) {  
    e.stopPropagation();
    UpdateAndRefreshTable('resub');
});
```

Notice that you do not need the `find()` function. IDs should be unique, so it should be sufficient to simply use the `#BtnResubmit` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are doing it wrong. With the current code you are registering an event for the child element when you click the parent.

So if you have any event bound on parent then you have to use `event.stopPropagation()` on child element to stop the event to bubbleup to the parent like this:

```
$("#spnMenuContainer").bind("click",function(e){
   /*----
   some other code here
   -----*/
});

$('#BtnResubmit').on('click', function(ev) {  
    ev.stopPropagation();
    UpdateAndRefreshTable('resub');
});
```

just move it out from the parent click event and put it outside of it.